# How to Inherit button with code from form1 to form2

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, button

I have a main form which is called `form` and a second form called `form2`. `Form` contains a button with a coded function inside. Now on my `form2` I have the same button which performs the same function on `form` or which I want it to perform the same function as form1.

On `form2` I have created a button of which I want it to use the same function from the `form1`. Now I want to be able to click the button from form2 and it calls the button funtion from form1.

I have done this but I don't know how I can make it work

Form1 (mainform)

```
    public Button newButton
    {
        get
        {
            return btnNewfile;
        }
    }
    public void SetLanguage(string cbolang)
    {
        cboLanguage.SelectedValue = cbolang;
    }
```

Form2

```
    public frmMain_Page _frmMainform;

    public FrmLanguage(frmMain_Page _frmMainform)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this._frmMainform = _frmMainform;
    }

    public frmMain_Page _Main
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    //from this button I can't get the main button from the main form
    private void btnCreatFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _frmMainform.newButton.btnNewfile; 

       //Error  19  'System.Windows.Forms.Button' does not contain a definition for 'btnNewfile' and no extension method 'btnNewfile' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)


    }
```

this is the button with coded function. am trying to take it from this button

```
    private void btnNewfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _frmMainform.newButton;

        XmlDocument _doc = new XmlDocument();

        FileInfo _fileInfo = new FileInfo(txtInputfile.Text);
        _InputFileName = _fileInfo.Name;
        _InputFileSourceDirectory = _fileInfo.DirectoryName;
        _InputFileExternsion = _fileInfo.Extension;

        _OutFileName = cboLanguage.SelectedItem.ToString() + "-language.resx";

        string outputFilePath = txtInputfile.Text.Replace(_InputFileName, _OutFileName);
        File.Copy(txtInputfile.Text, outputFilePath);
        string text = File.ReadAllText(outputFilePath);

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(outputFilePath);
        foreach (var valueNode in doc.Descendants("data").SelectMany(n => n.Elements("value")))
        {
            valueNode.Value = string.Empty;
        }
        foreach (var commentNode in doc.Descendants("data").SelectMany(n => n.Elements("comment")))
        {
            commentNode.Value = DeleteBetween(commentNode.Value, "Font");
            commentNode.Value = DeleteBetween(commentNode.Value, "DateStamp");
            commentNode.Value = DeleteBetween(commentNode.Value, "Comment");
        }
        doc.Save(outputFilePath);
        txtOutputfile.Text = _InputFileSourceDirectory + "\\" + _OutFileName;


        _doc.Load(outputFilePath);
        string xmlcontents = _doc.InnerXml;
        //lblversion.Text = updateversion.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: For one, this has nothing to do with inheritance. Two, you're trying to access `btnNewfile` of `_frmMainform.newButton`, that's obviously silly - you already have the button reference on `_frmMainform.newButton`. The error message is quite clear on that point. Three, don't. This is just a bad practice in general, and writing Delphi in C# isn't really a good way to work with C# :) Keep your dependencies in check, find out if you can separate the code out to a separate function that can be called from both button click events...

Comment: I am trying to get a direction from here. I am lost and am asking for anyone to show me on how i can do it

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnCreatFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // because newButton returns btnNewfile
    // You can access btnNewLife by : _frmMainform.newButton
    _frmMainform.newButton.Text = "My Button";
}
```

Also your newButton returns a Button object.
A Button object dose not have a child Button.
So you just need to access newButton to get btnNewLife.

Comment: Error 3 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: Yes i know. Because I found that you just get that button and dont do any action.

Comment: I just follow your code to edit. You should do other actions on that Button, such as `_frmMainform.newButton.Text = "My New Button"; `

Comment: the name should be for the first button from form1 or from form2 ?

Comment: from `_frmMainform` in form 2.

Comment: I have used button name from form1 and it says;
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I need a guidance here. the button got the code and now i don't understand why it says it is null..must i paste the button with the code? see my button with full code on it..

Comment: can i add you on skype if that's the case?

Comment: or tell me which code must i post so that you understand better

Comment: Please can you help me with this problem as i have been totally stuck

Comment: Hello Peter, am still waiting for working solution from you.   
thanks!